# Mac App to display most recently added photo to folder

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, photos

Is there any Mac app to display the most recently added image to a folder?

The use case is a wireless camera card that sends the images to a folder, and we would like to see the image on a monitor.

Comment: You should be able to set up a folder-actions automator script to watch a folder, and when the contents change, run a program, etc.  http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_folder_actions_automator is a nice concise summary of what you'd need to do.

Comment: There should be some application that can do this. Maybe the preview app is sufficient with the automator?